# How to bootstrap AlethZero on Morden testnet?

Tags: testnets, cpp-ethereum, alethzero, morden

[I am](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/4380/alethzero-morden-problem-in-connecting-peers#latest) trying to use the testnet using AlethZero. I use this command `alethzero --morden` as suggested in the wiki. It does not seem to connect to any peer and hence does not sync the blocks. I also tried to connect to the testnet using `eth --morden` command with no success.

If I use AlethZero in the main chain, it syncs perfectly.

AlethZero version is 1.1.1. Any suggestion why this might occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are much fewer nodes on Morden than on the main network.

- 6377 on the main network right now (http://ethernodes.org/network/1)
- 344 on Morden (http://ethernodes.org/network/2)

We have also had issues in the past (which might still be present), of the hardcoded "seed nodes" in the testnet not actually being online, so new Morden nodes are unable to discover live nodes to get themselves started.

Just try again.  Sometimes there are times of the day where more people are working on testing, so they start Morden nodes.

If you keep having the issue for another day or two, please log an issue on http://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella and we can investigate further.   Perhaps we need to change some of the seed node settings for Morden?